# How to verify in-app purchase transaction itself successful Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I have this code for my in-app purchase

```
string receipt = await Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID, false);
```

The documentation states that this method returns a success value even if:

```
there's no network connection available
the user cancels out of the dialog
the user's authentication fails

You should treat a success result as indicating the async process completed without      
errors. To ensure that the transaction itself was successful, check the   
LicenseInformation element in the returned receipt.
```

Is there a quick way to verify the receipt for the particular item actually successful before I unlocked the purchase feature? Currently if there's no error, the feature will always be unlocked because the receipt isn't verified.

My code:

```
    private async void inAppPurchase(string key)
    {

        if (!Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive)
        {
            try
            {
                // The customer doesn't own this feature, so 
                // show the purchase dialog.
                MockIAPLib.ListingInformation li = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
                string pID = li.ProductListings[key].ProductId;

                //purchase successful
                string receipt = await Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID, false);

                //Check the receipt for 

                switch (key)
                {
                    case "IsAdsVisibleSetting":
                        settings.IsAdsVisibleSetting = false;
                        break;
                    case "style_2":
                        fontFolder[key] = true;
                        settings.AllowedFontSetting = fontFolder;
                        break;
                    case "backgrounds_2":
                        backgroundGroups[key] = true;                          
                        settings.AllowedBackgroundGroupsSetting = backgroundGroups;
                        break;
                    case "backgrounds_3":
                        backgroundGroups[key] = true;
                        settings.AllowedBackgroundGroupsSetting = backgroundGroups;
                        break;
                }

                RenderStoreItems();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the in-app purchase was not completed because an error occurred.", "Purchasing Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after purchase method call, make sure to check the license is active or not before full fulling the goods. If it is consumable type, call ReportProductFulfillment() method.

```
CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive
```

BTW, in your code includeReceipt value is set as false - will keeps 'receipt' as empty always.